# how to convert list of data as json in flutter dart to call API

Tags: flutter

I want to convert list to json to call and fetch API data, how do I do that

```
List value = [
val,
val2
]
```

here is the list

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: hi, is the list, when converted to JSON, going to be used as the body of post request ?

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude i don understand what your asking

Comment: okay how do you want to call and fetch API data. like let us say we answer your question, how would you use the json? this will guide in helping you

Comment: use jsonEncode(list);